# How do I get the position of the selected Illustrator PathItem in pixels using?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, extendscript

I have a simple problem, but can't seem to find my way around it:
I have PathItem and Illustrator points out that it is at position (781px,250px).

How can I get those values in jsx ?

I've noticed that the **PathItem** inherits the position property from **PageItem**, and position
is a **Point**, but when I try to print the values, I get *undefined*:

```
$.writeln(app.activeDocument.selection[0].position.x);
```

If I leave out .x from the line above I get this printed in the console:

```
521,510
```

What are these values ? Are they x,y coordinates ? In what unit ? How can I convert to pixels ?

Why can I not access x,y/top,left properties ?

I'm using Illustrator CS5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@bradido's answer is helpful, it is incomplete.

It seems Illustrator has different coordinate systems: an overall document coordinate system and a second based on the currently-active artboard (you may have several defined but only one is 'active' at a time.) One has the origin at the centre of the document while the other has the origin at top-left. Also it's Y values increase upwards.

It is wise to first check for the coordinate system using the `app.coordinateSystem` property, and if needed, there is a conversion function (`doc.convertCoordinate`) which handles the offset from the centre.

Here's an snippet which demonstrates how to retrieve x,y values for symbols in Illustrator, which can later be used in actionscript (using the coordinate system conversion):

```js
var doc = app.activeDocument;
var sel = doc.selection;
var selLen = sel.length;
var code = 'var pointsOnMap:Vector.<Vec> = Vector.<Vec>([';
for(var i = 0 ; i < selLen ; i++){
    var pos = doc.convertCoordinate(sel[i].position, app.coordinateSystem, CoordinateSystem.ARTBOARDCOORDINATESYSTEM);
    code += 'new Vec('+(pos[0] + (sel[i].width * .5)).toFixed(2) + ' , ' + Math.abs((pos[1] - (sel[i].height*.5))).toFixed(2); // Math.abs(pos-height) - same for both coord systems ?
    if(i < selLen-1) code +=  '),';
    else             code +=  ')]);pointsOnMap.fixed=true;';
}
$.writeln(code);
```

For more details, see this [thread on the Adobe Forums](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/784698?decorator=print&displayFullThread=true).

Comment: Just an FYI.  You can eliminate `hasDocCoords` and your ternary operator by simply passing in `app.coordinateSystem` directly, like this: `var pos = doc.convertCoordinate(sel[i].position, app.coordinateSystem, CoordinateSystem.ARTBOARDCOORDINATESYSTEM);`

Comment: For that matter, you can eliminate the final `if` clause and replace it with a ternary operator itself (e.g. `code += (i < selLen-1) ?  '),' : ')]);pointsOnMap.fixed=true;';`

Comment: Very good point ! I totally missed that back then. Thank you for pointing that out. I've updated the snippet as advised. Unfortunately I no longer have access to Illustrator to test: hopefully it still works :)

Comment: Glad I can help!  And yes, it does work!  Just wrote my own and used exactly that. :)

Answer (score 2):

The Point is an array of the positions. So to get the coordinates:

```
x = app.activeDocument.selection[0].position[0];

y = app.activeDocument.selection[0].position[1];
```

Comment: The values returned by selection[0].position are different from the ones visible in the property inspector (x,y values). That is my problem.

Answer (score 2):

The example above is good but is for a very specific task. Here is a function that will do the correct coordinate conversion and return the center:

```js
function convertPoint(item){
    var pos = doc.convertCoordinate (item.position, CoordinateSystem.DOCUMENTCOORDINATESYSTEM, CoordinateSystem.ARTBOARDCOORDINATESYSTEM);
    pos[0] += item.width * 0.5;
    pos[1] = Math.abs(pos[1] - (item.height * 0.5));
    return pos;
}
```

You must pass the ITEM not the point. And I must vent: the need to do this is not a good idea.